# httpd: Route all incoming http requests from Angular client to C++ application

Tags: c++, apache

Currently I'm using a simple web server **I wrote** in C++
This application parses an HTTP message sent from an Angular client and acts upon.
The motivation: The C++ application has to access hardware. It can't be done with Javascript (for example)
This C++ application is launched only once till system shutdown.

I consider the following change:
The target (linux) will run httpd.
httpd will route all HTTP requests to my C++ application.
But the C++ application will be launched once upon initialization of httpd.
Is it possible ?  How ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: One possibility would be to have the web server talk to your C++ process via [FastCGI](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html).

Comment: Maybe a simple web-redirect in the web-server config file? Consult your web-server documentation. Then you don't need to change your C++ application,

Comment: Jerry, Galik: Thank you very much !